# Is it possible to automatically open the mic input on keyboard?

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

There is a little mic button on the keyboard that when pressed allows the users to vocally talk the text into a text view. Is it possible to automatically force this mic as soon as the text view is pressed? As to not have them go through the hassle of having to click on the mic button themselves? This is what I am talking about:[this](http://s14.postimg.org/rgr4ohw35/Screen_Shot_2015_02_20_at_3_58_00_AM.png)

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look a the [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardAppearance) documentation, I see no way of showing the voice-input mode automatically.

This would also make sense, since there are a lot of languages which don't have this feature.